# Need help searching if a line in a csv file contains a word

Tags: python

I am writing some code. I would like to have an `if` statement that if a row in the CSV file contains what you input (a single word) then it does something.

I have tried doing `if row = input then do this` but it doesn't work as the whole row does not = the input only part of it does.

```
for row in reader:
    if row == input1:
        # Whatever I want
```

It does nothing, as the entire row does not equal `input1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `if input1 in row:`

Comment: can i do "not in"?

Comment: Nvm i figured out 'not in' exists!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if row[0]==input1:
```

This will check if the first element in the row is equal to input1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following.

```
with open('country.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()

for line in data:
    if "Switzerland" in line:
        print(line)
```